# Im trying to put an angular slider in a laravel project

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, laravel

Im trying to put an Angularjs image slider into a laravel project, this is the code for the view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.1.js"></script>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

`var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
     app.controller('CarouselDemoCtrl', CarouselDemoCtrl);`

```
    function CarouselDemoCtrl($scope){
      $scope.myInterval = 3000;
      $scope.noWrapSlides = false;
      $scope.activeSlide = 0;
      $scope.slides = [
        {
          image: 'images/hotel1.jpg'
        },
        {
          image: 'images/piscina1.jpg'
        },
        {
          image: 'images/pool1.jpg'
        },
        {
          image: 'images/presidencial1.jpg'
        }
      ];
    }
    </script>
    <title>Papayon Resorts</title>
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
        @if (Route::has('login'))
            <div class="top-right links">
                @if (Auth::check())
                    <a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Inicio</a>
                @else
                    <a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Iniciar Sesión</a>
                    <a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Registro</a>
                @endif
            </div>
        @endif
        <div class="content">
            <div class="title m-b-md">
                Papayon Resorts
            </div>
            <div class="links">
                <a href="/habitaciones/">Habitaciones</a>
                <a href="/promosiones">Paquetes de promoción</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
    <div ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl" id="slides_control">
            <div>
                <uib-carousel interval="myInterval" active="activeSlide">
                    <uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" index="$index">
                        <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto; height: 500px; width: 700px" ><!-- this is the line where I have the error-->
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                        </div>
                    </uib-slide>
                </uib-carousel>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

but when I do this it tells me this error

Below is is the error I get:

[image]

**Any idea of how to solve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `@` symbol to inform the Blade rendering engine an expression should remain untouched

Change this

```
<img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto; height: 500px; width: 700px" ><!-- this is the line where I have the error-->
```

to

```
<img ng-src="@{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto; height: 500px; width: 700px" ><!-- this is the line where I have the error-->
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#blade-and-javascript-frameworks